# Simple Function for S(n) Big Oh

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, recurrence

[image]

Give a simple function f(n) so that the sum S(n) is in Θ(f(n)).

I don't know where to get started for this, I know the definition of Big Oh, and Big Theta but I'm unsure how to formulate a function from the Sum S(n).

Comment: This is probably a better fit for math.stackexchange or cs.stackexchange

Comment: I agree with @DennisMeng --you may also want to include any other requirements.. are you being asked to graph the function with ie. Maple? Or just simply come up with a function that runs in linear time?

Comment: @RobertoNavarro Just looking for a function. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: How familiar are you with Sum functions? That is definitely mathematical understanding. Assuming you know what the sum function is, how might you write an algorithm to calculate it? What's the BIG-O of that algorithm?

Comment: O(n^8), because sum(i^k)=O(n^(k+1)). You can calculate sum like this with generating function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function or other methods.

Answer (score 3):

1. ∑ i^5 < n * n^5 =n^6
2. ∑ i^5 > n/2 * (n/2)^5 = n^6 / 64

1,2 → ∑ i^5 ∈ Θ(n^6)  (3)

(3)→ ∑ i^5 * n^2 ∈ Θ(n^8)

Answer (score 0):

Not only you can easily approximate this sum, you can actually calculate it exactly using [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).

Using it you get:

[image], which you should multiply by `n^2`. So the complexity is `O(n^8)`.